# Removing non-matching filenames from a list - Python

Tags: python, string, directory

I'm reading the files name from a directory. I am then chopping the output so I only have the first 10 characters from the filename, because of this is causes the output to have duplicates and file names I don't want included.
This is my code:

```
import os

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\\Users\User\Documents'):
   for filename in files:
        f = os.path.join(path, filename)
        print (str(f)[25:35])
```

This returns a list like this:

```
NUMBER0001
NUMBER0002
NUMBER0003
XXXXXXXX11
XXXXXXXX11
XXXXXXXX11
```

Expected Output:

```
NUMBER0001
NUMBER0002
NUMBER0003
```

How do I remove the files that don't start with 'NUMBER' from the list or how do I remove files that have `XXX` at the start?

Also, is it possible to sort the output so it is in order of creation date?(The numbers at the end of the file name do not reference the order that the files were created).

Comment: please write an expected outup

Comment: Not sure I'm clear - are we removing *duplicates*, or names that *don't match the specified pattern*?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code is for taking only filenames which have the "NUMBER" prefix.

```
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\\Users\User\Documents'):
   for filename in files:
        if 'NUMBER' in filename:
            f = os.path.join(path, filename)
            print (str(f)[25:35])
```

Comment: .startswith method appears to be better suited for this purpose, to avoid cases of "XXXXNUMBER001" Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539959/finding-whether-a-string-starts-with-one-of-a-lists-variable-length-prefixes

Comment: @Kryesec I agree. Although I thought an "if" condition would suffice as per the list that JackU has shown us.